# What is the difference between ‘wake up’ and ‘wake’?

Tags: difference, verbs, usage

> 1. My wife was asleep, and I **woke up** her.
> 2. My wife was asleep, and I **woke** her.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is not much difference.

Phrasal verbs with "up" tend to indicate "completeness of action". It suggests that either she didn't (couldn't) go back to sleep, or she at least became awake enough to talk. You would probably use "woke up" more often in this context

You might prefer "woke" in negative contexts:

> She didn't wake as I came quietly into the room.

There is a third word for you to look up "awoke" which has a slightly different meaning (it is usually intransitive) (but check a dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are semantically similar and grammatically correct except the mistake in the order of words in the  first sentence:

"My wife was asleep, and I woke ***her up.***"

Though you can say:
"I woke up my wife".

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/wake[1]) 
:

***Wake***

: to cause (a person or animal) to be awake after sleeping

// The sound of children shouting woke me.

— often + up

// Don't hesitate to wake me up if you need anything at all.

Comment: But I see ‘ woke up her ‘ in my book.

Comment: It is very rare though possible like: "She opened her mouth to wake up her aunt but it was to heavy an effort, it required too much energy". (https://books.google.ru/books?id=xkikwkzkakYC&q=%22wake+up+her%22&dq=%22wake+up+her%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGoP643dvhAhUMcZoKHbEKAN4Q6AEIMTAE).   But "wake her up" is preferable (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wake+her+up%2C+wake+up+her&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwake%20her%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwake%20up%20her%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Can I use ‘wake her up’ instead of ‘wake up her’ in your case?

Comment: I would recommend WAKE HER UP only.

Comment: Even registered examples with "wake up her" are of different type: ...wake up. Her... or: ...wake up her (possessive pronoun). In your case there is an   object pronoun.